# Recover bricked "Asus Transformer Pad TF300T"

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.0-lollipop, unbricking

PLEASE HELP ME BECAUSE I HAVE SCREWED MY TABLET UP!!!!

I have a device "Asus Transformer Pad TF300T" running on Cyanogenmod CM12.1 Snapshot build (Custom ROM).

For some reason my Google account was not working properly on my tablet, nor could I add an account to it.

When I did a factory reset on my tablet, after it restarted, a screen named "TeamWin" showed up on my tablet, it was stuck to that screen and would flash black and the same screen and it did this on a loop.

My question is do you know how do I recover from such problem, please let me know as I would like to fix and use my tablet again, thank you :)

Comment: Do you have adb on your PC? IF so, this will be a piece of cake.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get your device to show up in your PC, or if not, there is luckily a way to revive your device. Before we begin, I present you with [this firmware file](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/get/jenkins/50986/cm-10.2.0-tf300t.zip). Download it, and keep it safe. we may need it.

Alright, so here is the method. If you can make your device appear in a PC, in recovery (teamwin) then just move the above file to a folder on the Transformer's SD card. Then on your device, pick "install update from sd" and find that file. Tap it, then wait. If it succeeds, you WILL be on CM 10.2 (Android 4.3) now, but its better than the alternative.