# need further info on how to recover a bricked Asus Transformer Pad TF300T

Tags: cyanogenmod, unbricking

I've got the exact same problem as the fellow over at https://android.stackexchange.com/a/126418/170164

I'm not a programmer or developer by any means - only came across this site searching for an answer to the problem - but I'm pretty good at poking around & following instructions, and ultimately problem solving.

So I don't quite get some of the instructions in the answer provided.

Yes, I've got adb.  And I got the right drivers.  And I edited the Windows path so I can more easily use adb.

So here's the original answer:
*If you can make your device appear in a PC, in recovery (teamwin) then just move the above file to a folder on the Transformer's SD card. Then on your device, pick "install update from sd" and find that file. Tap it, then wait. If it succeeds, you WILL be on CM 10.2 (Android 4.3) now, but its better than the alternative.*

adb devices command does show my device in recovery

So, if I understand, I use the adb push command to move the file (which I saved in my downloads).  So, is this right?
adb push c:\locationofthefile\filename.zip /sdcard/filename.zip
(assuming lower/upper case doesn't matter?)

I got that far.  cmd is waiting on my next command.  I don't know how to access the device (since being able to access it, is, after all, what I'm trying to do here) in order to install the file from the sd card.  I assume it's something I have to do with adb, but haven't a clue where to start.

So, how do I follow the rest of the answer: "*pick "install update from sd" and find that file. Tap it, then wait.*"  ???  Please help!

Comment: also - the firmware is zipped.  So will I have to somehow unzip it via adb before installing it from the sdcard?

Comment: Have you installed a custom recovery, or are you on the stock recovery? If you have teamwin recovery (TWRP), you can just select the zip file via the recovery GUI.

Comment: Thanks, Dan.  The screen is flashing Teamwin (it's stuck there).  Not sure what you mean by the "recovery GUI"?